# Pass grep output to variable and use that variable as input to sed in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm looking to write a shell script that grabs a line number from a file using grep, and use that line numbers as head and tail for sed command to cut the file.

My script looks something like this:

```
head=$(grep -n -i -B 1 "^\s\+abcd" <sourcefilename> | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f1)
tail=$(grep -n -i  -B 1 " efgh" <sourcefilename>  | tail -n 1| cut -d: -f1)

if($head!=NULL)
then
        sed -n "$head,$tailp" <sourcefile>.txt > <newfile>.txt
fi
```

My goal, is to use first grep, and get the head line number when it matches the pattern, then use the second grep to get tail line number when it matches the pattern, and use those to as inputs for sed with -n switch and create a file that only has line numbers from head to tail.

If I execute it individually against the file, like

```
grep -n -i "^\s\+abcd" <filename> | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f1 , it gives me 11 and 
grep -n -i  " efgh" <filename>  | tail -n 1| cut -d: -f1 gives me 106.
```

Then I used these numbers as inputs and do

```
sed -n 11,106 <sourcefile>.txt > <newfile>.txt
```

it works perfectly. I'm trying to automate the process to have a script that can run against multiple files at once.

Also, the if statement with NULL means when grep doesn't return anything, just don't run the loop, which seems to also error out.

Comment: Please post some sample data we can work with.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: com.new.security.JXSecurityException: No certificates encoded in supported ways were found
at com.tibco.security.CertUtils.streamToCerts(CertUtils.java:634)
at com.tibco.ae.tools.palettes.generalpalette.ImportTrustedCertCommand.buttonPressed(ImportTrustedCertAction.java:133)
at com.tibco.ae.designerapi.forms.ConfigForm.actionPerformed(ConfigForm.java:1326)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at com.tibco.security.CertUtils.streamToCerts(CertUtils.java:626)
... 86 more

Comment: For example there is this above stack trace. Use:

grep -n -i "^\s\+at" sample.txt | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f1
grep -n -i  " more" sample.txt  | tail -n 1| cut -d: -f1

Comment: `$tailp` is trying to expand a variable named `tailp`.  If you want the value in the variable `tail` followed by a `p`, use `${tail}p`

Comment: But why aren't you just letting sed do the match for you? `sed -n  '/^  *abcd/,/ efgh/p' sourcefile`.  If you need a case insensitive match, some sed provide nice way to do that but even `sed -n '/^  *[Aa][Bb][Cc][Dd]/,/ [eE][fF][gG][hH]/p' sourcefile` is cleaner than trying to prematch with grep.

Comment: If you look at the grep above I'm not just grepping a pattern but also using -B to get a line above the pattern to be printed or considered for sed command to print. If I just use AWK or Sed, I cannot do that rather, I'll end up only grabbing what's in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably solve that with awk only. First some data:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
$ awk '/2/,/4/' file
2
3
4
```

You could replace the `2` and `4` with your proper regexen for the head and the tail.

**Edit**: an example of `grep -B 1`:

```
$ awk '/2/{f=1;print p} f{print} /4/{f=""} {p=$0}' file
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Hi james,

I don't understand how this is solving the issue. I used awk in place of sed, and it looks like this: 

awk '$head,$tail' file.txt

Where my grep from above example grabs the needed value and passes it to head and tail. That awk command when executed inside the script simply error'd out with "awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `file.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)"

Comment: @komar already filled the blanks for you, ie. _replace the 2 and 4 with your proper regexen for the head and the tail_. I didn't want to do it as there was no data to test against.

Comment: If you look at the grep above I'm not just grepping a pattern but also using -B to get a line above the pattern to be printed or considered for sed command to print. If I just use AWK or Sed, I cannot do that rather, I'll end up only grabbing what's in the pattern.

Comment: @Tk_93 Added an example in awk of `grep -B 1`. Sorry I missed it, I usually don't read non-working code, kind of expected sample data and expected output.

Comment: in my comments above I provided sample data that can be copied into a txt file and use the script above to get the results that I got. Example run the first grep command for the sample data and you'll get a number x, run the second grep you'll get number y, now use number x and y as inputs in Sed and you'll see the output file. 

One thing I forgot to do is to add random strings above and below the stack trace, add some random lines above and below the stack trace and then perform the test. In the new file you'll see how it grabs only the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need grep to search patterns, you can use sed or awk only:

```
sed -nE '/^\s+abcd/,/ efgh/p' sourcefile.txt
```

or

```
awk '/^\s+abcd/,/ efgh/{print}' sourcefile.txt
```

or more simple (by default awk just print lines)

```
awk '/^\s+abcd/,/ efgh/' sourcefile.txt
```

`/pattern1/,/pattern2/{commands}` common for sed and awk to work with lines between /pattern1/ and /pattern2/.
In your case you just print output for.

Comment: If you look at the grep above I'm not just grepping a pattern but also using -B to get a line above the pattern to be printed or considered for sed command to print. If I just use AWK or Sed, I cannot do that rather, I'll end up only grabbing what's in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

sed -n "$linenum,\$p" $infile >> source.csv

This actually worked for me with the sample data. It get me all the lines starting from head till end of file.